# Flutter: Dart - How to Show Stored Variable?

Tags: string, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have **two dart pages**. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1xaf.png

In 2nd Page I have scrabbed text from a website and **stored the value in a string** called `fetchedstring` and it is printing the strings in **console** command line using the command `print`.

But I want this string to be showed in my **main dart page**.

How to do that?

```
//DART FILE 1 HAS THE FOLLOWING CODE 
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './function.dart';
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget 
{
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) 
{
return new MaterialApp(
home: new Scaffold(
appBar: new AppBar(),
body: new Center(
child: new String(fetchedtext),//Here I Want The Fetched Text
),
),
);
}
}
//DART PAGE 2 HAS THE FOLLOWING CODE
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as parser;
import 'package:html/dom.dart';
mainz() async 
{
http.Response response = await http.get('https://www.google.com');    
Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
document.getElementsByTagName('a').forEach((Element element)
{
final String fetchedText = element.text;
print(fetchedText);
}
);
}
//I WANT THAT String "fetchedtext" to be displayed in my Dart Page1.
```

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish and what you tried.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the text there.

Comment: Please ensure proper formatting of the code. If you want people to invest time to answer your question, then you should put some effort into it to ask a proper question. Properly formatting the code is part of that.

Comment: I have done something,lastly and i seriously don't know how to format the questions,sorry but i have attahed a image file in the 1st line of my question!!!

Comment: Just copy/past the formatted code. Select the code and click the `{}` button in the toolbar.

Comment: Yes i did now,and i hope its okay now???!!!??

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of what you are trying to do is correct, then you need to paste this at the very end of you `function.dart` file:

```
List get_elements() {
  http.Response response = await http.get('https://www.google.com');    
  Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
  document.getElementsByTagName('a').forEach((e) => print(e));
  return document.getElementsByTagName('a');
}
```

Then modify one line in your `main.dart`:

```
child: get_elements().first;
```

Note that if you don't want to return the first found element, just remove first and use [] to chose what element you want to get, or if you want to get the whole list, just delete `.first`, but then you will get a String.

Comment: Bro i applied your code,and showed an error that "first is not mentioned as a element in List funciton>>>>Let me clearly say my motive,,The program gets the text data from google and displays in my Laptop's console Display,But my targte is i want that texts to be shown in my App's Body.In order to show that scrabbed texts,i have tried to store them in a string and called them back to my App's Scaffold Body.......the only problem is "I don't know how to store that texts in a string/varriable and calling them back"

Answer (score 0):

Use [Futurebuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget
{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    var builder = FutureBuilder(
      future: mainz(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print(snapshot.error);
          return new Text("${snapshot.error}");
        }
        return snapshot.hasData
            ? new Center(
          child: Text(snapshot.data), //Here I Want The Fetched Text
        )
            : new CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Title"),
        ),
        body: builder,
      )
    );
  }
}

Future<String>  mainz() async
{
  await new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 3));
  return 'Sample data';
}
```